# C# EF if row exists in table one select it else select from another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having two tables `T1` and `T2`.

```
T1
---------
(Name,Value)

T2
---------
(Name,Value)
```

I'm trying to make a select on `T1` based on `Name` and if it doesn't exist then select the row from `T2`

```
var T1Row = db.T1.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.Name == "text1").FirstOrDefault();
if (T1Row == null)
    T1Row = db.T2.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.Name == "text2").FirstOrDefault();
```

But I'm getting `Cannot implicitly convert type T2 to T1`. I'm trying to make this two queries as a single one but I don't know how.

I'm new to C# programming, so please be gentle

Comment: T1Row is strongly typed with T1 so you can't use same variable for getting T2 records. So try to use different variable for second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two queries result in different types. 
Looks like you need [DTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) classes. In that way you can select your data in required format and return to your [BLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705600/uses-of-business-logic-layer).

```
public class NameValueDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value{ get; set; }
}

var T1Row = db.T1.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.Name == "text1").Select(i => new NameValueDTO { Name = i.Name, Value = i.Value }).FirstOrDefault();
if (T1Row == null)
    T1Row = db.T2.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.Name == "text2").Select(i => new NameValueDTO { Name = i.Name, Value = i.Value }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

`T1` and `T2` are different types (even if they have the exact same properties), consider using an interface, or selecting/projecting into a common object

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this error because `db.T1` and `db.T2` are different class types.  One option is to have the two classes you're using for `T1` and `T2` implement the same interface.  Then, instead of using `var`, use the interface type when declaring `T1Row`:

```
IMyInterface T1Row = db.T1.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.Name == "text1").FirstOrDefault();  //both the types in T1 and T2 need to implement this interface.
if (T1Row == null)
    T1Row = db.T2.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.Name == "text2").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: but these are DB tables, not sure we need to implement `interface` for ORM mapped classes

Comment: @Alexey - The fact that the collections `db.T1` and `db.T2` represent database tables is unrelated to the compile time error OP is seeing.  C# is statically typed, and the type of `T1Row` is bound on the very first line to whatever type `T1` is.  Trying to automatically convert from whatever type `T1` is to whatever type `T2` is (which OP is doing on the 3rd line) will result in a compile time error.

Comment: You should use a DTO or POCO to encapsulate the data not an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Select` function to convert T1 or T2 objects to an object (nor T1, neither T2) that contains the properties (*Name* and *Value*) that you need in return.